# Using file.get() with integer values

Tags: c++, file-io

I need to read numeric values by using get().
I have this code that deal with char as input this is a part of the code. How can update on this code to use get() with values in correct way?

```
in_file.open(in_file_name, ios::in);
    in_file.get(id);         // id that I need to use it,int id. With original code  
                                // was  char id;
    while (!in_file.eof())
    {
        in_file.get(id);
    }
    in_file.close();
```

The error that I have:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type
> 'std::basic_istream::char_type&' {aka 'char&'} to an rvalue of
> type 'std::basic_istream::char_type' {aka 'char'}
> in_file.get(id);

Comment: *I need to read numeric values by using get()* Why?

Comment: [`istream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) traffics in `char` values. If you have to use it to read an integer you have to read all of the characters that make up the input, convert each one into a digit, and convert the result into an integer. That's what `operator>>` does.

Comment: @kayla `get` only reads `char` values. So it you want to read integers with `get` then you have to call `get` multiple times and convert the characters you have read into an integer. That's pretty much what `>>` does for you. So the unexplained part of you question is why you need to read integers with `get`. If you can explain why that is then maybe the right thing to do will be more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read integers use `>>` not `get`. Plus your while loop is wrong. Here's the correct code

```
in_file.open(in_file_name, ios::in);
while (in_file >> id)
{
    ...
}
in_file.close();
```

Comment: The code that I posted used char as input ant it work with out errors. but I need to use it with int values as input therefor I am asking how to use get() with int

Comment: @kayla You cannot use `get` with `int` it is for `char` only. Perhaps you should explain why you **need** to use `get`.

Comment: Thank you so much John, you save my day!

Comment: @kayla -- and the added bonus is that `>>` will work just fine to read a `char` if that's what you need: `char ch; std::can >> ch;`.

Comment: How can print this in_file >> id ?

Comment: @kayla `cout << id;` or if you mean to a file then `out_file << id;` where `out_file` is a file you've opened for output.